# Pre check a browser's media (video file) support

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, video-streaming

Is it possible to pre check a browser's media (video file) compatibility when the HTML page is ready???

There are probable options for HTML5 but i want it for general use. The application here is that i want to show not supported before the file is clicked on to stream if the file is not supported by the browser.

Thanks,
Sunny Pandya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DeviceAtlas](http://deviceatlas.com/) to determine media capabilities based on the User Agent.

If this doesn't suit you then try [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) feature detection.

Comment: DeviceAtlas does not seem to be free. Is there any open source option?

Comment: @darry.ten - There is a problem that my web-application is such that i may not be connected to internet. There must be some mechanism or database that gives me some information about the browser supported video formats.

Comment: Your Web application may not be connected to the Web?

Comment: If it is is HTML5/JavaScript you can also use Modernizr, although their wiki says the video capabilities detection may not be 100% reliable. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: yes it renders content directly from a hard drive and may not necessarily connect to internet. I cannot explain about the application due to disclosure limitations. And i m checking out modernizr

Comment: i did look into mordenizr but which API gives us such information

Comment: Is there any approach using lighttpd sever or python django framework for the same?